# Django: use get_prep_value() to remove dollar signs?

Tags: django, django-models

Is it advisable to use get_prep_value() in my Django Field subclass to do this (my custom field is a sub-class of DecimalField):

```
def get_prep_value(self, value):
    from decimal import Decimal
    value = Decimal(value.replace('$', ''))
    return super(MyCustomField, self).get_prep_value()
```

Does this pose a problem with django's ModelForm validation (ie, will ModelForm's validation see the decimal field subclass and not allow a $ to ever reach the model layer? Should I make a custom form field and set it as the default in this model field? Is there other issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this in the form field, since it's an issue that will only happen with form input.